# Jest/React Testing Library test failing - react router link click not working as expected

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a failing test but can't work out why. I have react-router links which link to the URL structure: `/classes/${weekday}`.

Classes component then sets the activeWeekday in context by React Router location which is displayed by the Classes as `{activeWeekday} Classes`

Functionality works i nthe browser, but for some reason in my tests it's not updating the header so the test is failing.

`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /friday classes/i`

Can anyone see why? I can't figure it out.

Thks so much in advance.

Update - [Here is a codepen replicating the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hamilton-h6ptyl?file=/src/components/classes/__tests__/classes.test.tsx).

```js
// Snapshot of the state passed to Classes via context
export const ClassesProvider = ({ children }: ClassesProviderProps) => {
  const [activeWeekdayNumber, setActiveWeekdayNumber] = useState<number>(
    new Date().getDay()
  );

// Classes component
const Classes = () => {
  const { activeWeekdayNumber, setActiveWeekdayNumber } = useContext(ClassesContext);
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const day = location.pathname.replace("/classes/", "");
    const dayIndex = daysOfWeekArray.indexOf(capitaliseFirstLetter(day));
    if (dayIndex !== -1) {
      setActiveWeekdayNumber(
        daysOfWeekArray.indexOf(capitaliseFirstLetter(day))
      );
    }
  }, [location, setActiveWeekdayNumber]);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{daysOfWeekArray[activeWeekdayNumber]} Classes</h2>
    </>
  );
};

// failing test - TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /friday classes/i
const setup = (value: ClassesContextType) =>
  render(
    <ClassesContext.Provider value={value}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Classes />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </ClassesContext.Provider>
  );

  test("displays the relevant heading when a day of the week link is clicked", () => {
    const value = {
      activeWeekdayNumber: 3, // wednesday
    };
    setup(value);
    const link = screen.getByRole("link", { name: "Friday" });
    fireEvent.click(link);
    expect(screen.getByText(/friday classes/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

The menu list is a styled link:

```js
<li>
        <HorizontalMenuLink $active={weekdayNumber === 1} to="/classes/monday">
          Monday
        </HorizontalMenuLink>
      </li>
```